# How to search multiple lines using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, networking, automation, multiline

I am looking for Python multiple line extraction using regex.

```
clock timezone EST -2 0

clock summer-time EDT recurring

!

ip dhcp snooping vlan 1-4094

no ip dhcp snooping information option

ip dhcp snooping

no ip domain-lookup

ip domain-name abc.com

ip device tracking probe auto-source override

!

crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-142154678
```

Regular expression I tried:

```
match = re.search(r"^ip dhcp.*/s+.*/s+.*/s+.*/s+.*/s+.*override",filename,flags=re.M).group(0)
```

But the problem is the number of lines are not fixed as it may be different on other devices as some commands could be missing.

So, what I am looking for here is to write a expression where I just mention the start point in the file and the end point and whatever there is the middle can be extracted. If I mention `\s+` then I am not sure how many lines are there in the middle as `.*` can't go to another line.

I am looking for something in the regex or any other solution where I can extract the configuration from starting point to end point as mentioned above irrespective of the lines missing in between.

Comment: Try `re.search(r"^ip dhcp.*(?:\n(?!!).*)*\n.*override",filename,flags=re.M)`.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. But if you don't mind can you please explain what (?:\n(?!!).*)*\n.* is doing here. I mean how it is covering the down lines

Comment: Before I do that, can you please confirm this is what you actually want? To get all lines after `ip dhcp` until the word `override` with no line starting with `!` in between them?

Comment: I am fine if ! is coming in between, let's say in Cisco devices "!" is very common between the configuration.  Yes I got the output but I am curious how middle part worked there and extracted the lines which I want till override. Because I have multiple regex to make of this nature. I really thank you for the solution and appreciate you if you can please share how to deal with string of same nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.search(r"^ip dhcp.*(?:\n(?!!).*)*\n.*override",filename,flags=re.M)
re.search(r"(?m)^ip dhcp.*(?:\n(?!!).*)*\n.*override",filename)
```

Note: if `override` should be matched as a whole word, enclose it with `\b`, i.e. `(?m)^ip dhcp.*(?:\n(?!!).*)*\n.*\boverride\b`.

The pattern matches

- `(?m)` - the `re.M` inline option (makes the `^` match start of any line)
- `^` - line start
- `ip dhcp` - a fixed string
- `.*` - the rest of  the line
- `(?:\n(?!!).*)*` - zero or more lines if not starting with `!`
- `\n` - a newline char
- `.*override` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then `override`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LvDpJ1/1).

On the Python side, it is not safe to directly chain the `.group()` method call after `re.search`. It is safer to get the match first, and if it succeeded, access the group value:

```py
match = re.search(r"(?m)^ip dhcp.*(?:\n(?!!).*)*\n.*override",filename)
if match:
    print(match.group())
```